# How to log the precise time when GUI got updated?

Tags: python, logging, kivy

I am developing an application for an experiment using Kivy library in Python. How can I log the precise time (with less than a second precision) when the GUI gets updated - some label changes or text appears?

It seems like the simple logging with the timestamp gives me very unprecise timing. Besides, I am using `Clock.schedule_once` to delay a GUI label update. That creates even more discrepancies between the log timestamps and the actual timing of things appearing on the screen.

Example of the code:

```
event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.doThing, 2)
logging.info('the thing is done')
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you are logging right now, but have you tried the `logging` module? The module allows formatting the output like `logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s') `. This should log in milliseconds

Comment: I have added an example to my question. The problem is that the logging happens before the event.

Comment: Put the `logging.info` call inside the `self.doThing` function.

Comment: For some reasons I am not getting the time in the logs. I tried 'logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s')' , didn't change anything. I know there is a kivy logging. Could it be using Kivy library native logger? 
The logs look like that:
[INFO   ] Logger: Record log in C:\filename

Answer (score 0):

well, unfortunately I don't quite understand what you want.
but if I got it right, you want to know how long it takes for your GUI to be updated?
I have an example that may be useful to you.

```
import time

start_count = time.time()

#Your script (put the part that does the gui update inside these two lines of code)

print(f"Finish in: {round(1000 * (time.time() - start_count))} ms ")
```

this will show you exactly how long it takes to execute everything between these two codes

ex:

```
import time
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab

start_count = time.time() #start count
px = ImageGrab.grab().load() # this will take a screenshot
print(f"Finish in: {round(1000 * (time.time() - start_count))} ms ") # how much he takes to finish
# if you want see how much he takes in seconds, you just need delete "1000 * "
```

Output:

```
Finish in: 38 ms
```